# How to create a DLL library in C++ and then use it in C project VisualStudio?

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2015

**How to create a DLL library in C++ and then use it in C project VisualStudio(2015) ?**

I've seen only 1 [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740263/c-dll-in-c-program) similar to my problem ,but I couldn't understand too much from it.

I've seen lots of tutorials on how to use .dll written in C++ into another C++ project, a C .dll used in C#, but no example of how to use a C++ .dll into a C VS project.
I really need help, I've searched all over the internet, tried all kind of 'solutions' to my problem, still, without any solution.

I really need your help on this one.

**The C++ dll Project has the following content :**

```
//C++ dll Header Library, having the name "dllDelay.h":

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void dllDelay(DWORD dwMsec);

#endif
```

---

```
//C++ .cpp file named "dllDelay.cpp":

#include "dllDelay.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

void dllDelay(DWORD dwMsec) {
Sleep(dwMsec);  
}
```

---

**The C VisualStudio(2015) Project has the following content :**

```
/*This function is intended to Delay 10 seconds, measure that elapsed time
and write it into a file. I've checked this function using Sleep() instead of
dllDelay() and it worked fine, so this function has no errors.*/

#include "dllDelay.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(void)
{
 FILE *write1;
 // measure elapsed time on windows with QueryPerformanceCounter() : 
 LARGE_INTEGER frequency;        // ticks per second
 LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;           // ticks
 double elapsedTime;
 write1 = fopen("write_difftime_1Test.txt", "w");
 fprintf(write1, "\n Sleep : 10000ms = 10s");

 time_t start, stop;
 clock_t ticks;
 long count;
 double i = 0, v = 0, j = 0;

  //make 10 such measurements and write them into file
 while ((j < 10) && ((write1 != NULL) && (TRUE != fseek(write1, 0L, SEEK_END))))
 {
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
    time(&start);

    //The function from dll
    dllDelay(10000);        

    time(&stop);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

    // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
    elapsedTime = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;
    fprintf(write1, "\n Elapsed time : %lf s.  timeDiff time: %f in seconds\n\n", elapsedTime / 1000, difftime(stop, start));

    j++;        
}
fclose(write1);

return 0;
```

}
`

This function is intended to Delay 10 seconds, measure that elapsed time
    and write it into a file. **I've checked this function using Sleep() instead of
    dllDelay() and it worked fine, so this function has no errors.**

**But when I use** `#include "dllDelay.h"`  **I get 3111 Errors** such as :

- expected a '{'
- identifier *write1 is undefined from `FILE *write1;`
- identifier clock_t is undefined from `clock_t ticks;`
- declaration is incompatible with "float log10(float_Xx)" (declared at line 227) - in cmath - a standard file where we have `using _CSTD log10; using _CSTD modf; using _CSTD pow;`
- declaration is incompatible with "double pow(double_Xx, int _Yx)" (declared at line 22) - in cmath - a standard file where we have `using _CSTD log10; using _CSTD modf; using _CSTD pow;`
- so in the file cmath - the whole file is signaled as being with errors
- and many other errors of such type - meaning that the 2 languages are mangled somehow.

I built the dll (in a dll project, of course), copied the .dll file into the C Project folder where the exe is found, I added to the solution Explorer the .lib file  and got these errors.

I really neeed your help, I've looked everywhere and did not found a guide or anything regarding the usage of a C++ .dll used in a C project. :|

*Thank you for your time.*

Comment: To begin with, `#include <iostream>` in the header file? How would that work when including your header file in a C project?

Comment: Also, `extern "C"` is specific for C++, you can't use it when including the header file in a C source file. That's why you will see `#ifdef __cplusplus` for conditional compilation of it in other header files.

Comment: Finally, in the C project where you use the DLL, you need to declare the function with `dllimport` instead. Use conditional compilation and macros to help you. Most tutorials should have told you about that.

Comment: I haven't found a complete tutorial from head to tail about using dllimport and macros because example were in the same programming language like C++ .dll used in C++  . I am trying to use dlls, this being my first time I make contact with dlls and disappointed not to find a complete guide. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C++ DLL project open the project properties and define a preprocessor symbol:

[image: Project properties screenshot]

Then in your header file, define another symbol based on whether the preprocessor symbol circled in red is defined or not:

```
#ifdef CPPDLL_EXPORTS
#define DLLIMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then use that defined symbol in front of your function declaration:

```
DLLIMPORT_EXPORT void dllDelay(DWORD dwMsec);
```

This has the following effect:

In your DLL project, the symbol (**DLLIMPORT_EXPORT**) is defined. Thus, DLLIMPORT_EXPORT will evaluate to **__declspec(dllexport)**. In your C project, which consumes the DLL, the symbol will not be defined. Ergo, DLLIMPORT_EXPORT evaluates to **__declspec(dllimport)** when the header file is included. Doing this will import the function and you will be able to use it. Failure to do so will result in a Linker error (*unresolved external symbol*) when trying to call the function.

Hope this helps!

PS: You should move all #includes that aren't needed in your header file to your implementation (CPP) file :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience. I'll try it right away :)